# How to make ASPNETDB.mdf appear?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I recently started to learn asp.net.I know that when you drag a login control on the page and a register control asp generates a database called ASPNETDB.mdf.I also know that this database should be in App_Data.For some reason after I added the login control , register control and also selected the authentification type to be from the internet the database is still not showing in App_Data.

How can I make it appear?

I need it to create a realationship with another table that will hold profile data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. I believe the file gets generated, but it's not included in the Web Application project automatically.

[image]